# Moving with slideshow with arrows on keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have on my website the same slideshow gallery as on this URL: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp.
I would like to have a moving gallery with the arrow keys on the keyboard.
Please, does anyone know, how to do it?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this code, it should works:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        plusSlides(-1)
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        plusSlides(1)
    }
});
</script>
```